# Is it possible to set image to ImageView from a path (external storage) on Android 10 and higher?

Tags: android, imageview, androidx, android-glide, android-external-storage

I need to show an image on ImageView from a picture located somewhere in the user's phone memory (External storage). I used image absolute path to achieve this and it worked well on any Android phone. But on Android 10 and above this strategy simply doesn't work (The loaded image is transparent). I know that from Android 10 Google made lots of changes to external memory accessibility, but still, is there a way to show an image from the external path?

I used both bitmap decoding and Glide to set image from path, but nothing works on Android 10+ :(

```
fun setImageFromPath(imagePath: String, imageView: ImageView){
            val imgFile = File(imagePath)
            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.absolutePath)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }
        }

fun setImageFromPathWithGlide(imagePath: String, imageView: ImageView, context: Context){
            Glide.with(context).asDrawable().load(Uri.fromFile(File(imagePath)))
                    .dontTransform()
                    .into(imageView)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. first add this line to the application manifest

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in your gradle file set this options(if its not)

```
 compileSdkVersion 29
```

and after obtaining permission to use access to memory - you can upload a picture

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me! But do you know if using legacy external storage will be supported in the future, let's say in Android 11+?